# Liveness / Readiness probe failed after upgrade to .Net Core 3.1

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I upgraded my .Net Core 2.1 to 3.1. After upgrade Liveness and Readiness probe to pods failed.
Below is my docker file snippet:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

When I check logs of the pod I get below errors:

> Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'
>
> Liveness probe failed: Get http://yyyy:80/: dial tcp yyyy:80: connect: connection refused

Here is my **Deployment.yaml** file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "staging.fullname" . }}
  namespace: staging
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "staging.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "staging.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "staging.name" . }}
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "staging.name" . }}
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.image.pullSecret }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
              value: "Staging"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 10  
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: provide complete deployment file with service and pod

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Added deployment.yaml file content

Comment: try binding to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

Comment: @HelloWorld Which place should I make that change? Just FYI now where I've mentioned in project to use url "http://localhost:5000".

Comment: In code of your application @User3250

Comment: @HelloWorld You mean in docker file?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your aspnet app. Please make sure port 80 is open, e.g. by removing health checks for a moment and trying to access the app. If you wont be able to access the app (connection gets refused) this would mean port 80 is not open and this is application issue. If you can access the app on port 80 this would mean its kubernetes issue with health checks.

Comment: @HelloWorld Connection gets refused after removing Liveness porbe. Not sure what might be causing the issue. 
I think this is what might be the cause of the issue "Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'"

Comment: on what port is the actual application running? is it 80 (probably not as `Connection gets refused`) or 5000? or maybe some other port and that's why its not working. Please identify the right ports.

Comment: When I execute curl command inisde the pod `localhost:5000` I do see my app running. But when I map port using `-p` in host machine, app doesn't work from host machine

Comment: ok, so your app is working on port 5000 not 80. So first of all bind your app to `0.0.0.0:5000` and not to `localhost:5000` so that its accessible from outside of the pod and also set your healthcheck to port 5000, not port 80

Comment: @HelloWorld Thanks a bunch! Changing url from `localhost:5000` to `0.0.0.0:5000` worked. Although wasn't easy to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was that kestrel server for .NET Core 3.1 was pointing to `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`. Hence, wasn't accessible from outside. Which is why liveness and readiness probes were failing.

To change url from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` I needed to add below section in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
      }
    }
  }
```

**Note:** `UseUrl()` method or setting environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` doesn't work for .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Thanks - adding the Kestrel config worked for me when a netcoreapp3.1 was updated to net7.0 and stopped working on Azure Kubernetes due to failing health checks.